# How can I install ChatGPT SEO plugin in ChatGPT?

Tags: plugins, openai-api

I learn about ChatGPT plugin in internet and below link.
https://techtrendingtopics.com/chatgpt-plugins-for-seo/

But I don't know how can I download and install this plugin?

1. SEO plugin
2. Core SEO AI Plugin
3. Aiprm
4. SEO Assistant
5. Bramework

Also please let me know, if it's safe to use this plugin in our SEO.

I don't get any download link of Core SEO AI plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go into the AIPRM website https://www.aiprm.com/ there is a link to install Chrome extension.

Chrome extension link
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aiprm-for-chatgpt/ojnbohmppadfgpejeebfnmnknjdlckgj?hl=en

This only provides you prompt and help you to add those prompts to the ChatGPT page so it's fully safe.

**If any website or plugin asks for your API Key to use CHatGPT functionality then stay away from those applications.**